# Sort by best matches mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have collection of data in Mongodb, i want to give best matches suggestion while user input query in our suggestion box,

when user start typing `com` suggestion should be:

- Computer
- Computer Science
- something more alike

I am sorting in Node by getting all matched data from mongo first and then give a rank to each data

```
function rank(name, q) {
    var len = name.length,
        lastIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        var n = name.indexOf(q[i], (lastIndex + 1));
        if(n !== -1) {
            len--;
            lastIndex = n;
        }
    }
    return len;
}
var query = 'com';
// giving rank to data
data = data.map(function(v) {
    v.rank = rank(v.value, query);
   return v;
});
// sorting by rank
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.rank - b.rank
});
```

It is giving me satisfied result, but it will be too slow while dealing with large data.
I want let mongodb engine to deal with sorting and give me just limited best matches result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do it through [`mapreduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/). Map-reduce is a data processing paradigm for condensing large volumes of data into useful aggregated results.

```
var mapFn = function(){
    var len = this.name.length,
        lastIndex = -1;
    var q = 'com';
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        var n = this.name.indexOf(q[i], (lastIndex + 1));
        if(n !== -1) {
            len--;
            lastIndex = n;
        }
    }
  emit(len, this);
};

var reduceFn = function(key, values){
  return values.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.name - b.name;
  });
};

db.collection.mapReduce(mapFn, reduceFn, { out: { reduce: 'result_collection'}});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support.
It is giving me undefined result. I dont think var `q` is accessible in `mapFn `function

Comment: @MdAdil, sorry for previous mistake, you could define `q = 'com'` as it shown in my answer.

Comment: @MdAdil, I did not test the above with huge data, it maybe one option or direction for you to solve your issue...

Comment: i want `q` from users. how can i get it in this function

Comment: @MdAdil, what I mentioned before, based on those codes are running in mongo shell. It seems you want to run your codes in `js` script. Maybe you could define `q` out of this function, as long as assign one value to it before the `mapFn` is called...

Comment: Yes, I am running it in nodejs with mongoose. global js variable isnt available in mongo script function, Is there way to inject values in mongo script function.